# Creating a pyramid of numbers with a certain logic

Tags: c++

I need a program that will output this figure:

```
         1
      1  2  1
   1  2  4  2  1
1  2  4  8  4  2  1
```

If you add the numbers on both ends, it will print the output beside it (inward). And then you will also add those two sums and print it again inwardly. Another thing, the input should be the largest number (in this case, number 8) It could be larger than 8 like the figure below.

```
            1
         1  2  1
      1  2  4  2  1
   1  2  4  8  4  2  1
1  2  4  8  16 8  4  2  1
```

In this case the input is 16. And so on. This is my latest program.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int i, j, k, b, a, space=10;

  for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
    for(k=0;k<space;k++){
      cout<<"   ";
    }
    for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j=j*2){
      cout<<j<<"  ";
    }
    space--;
    cout<<endl;
  }

  system("pause");
  return 0;

}
```

Please help me improve this. It's not yet a pyramid. Help me to output the desired figure at least.

Comment: Your program doesn't get close to a solution to the problem you are trying to solve... first of all you should read the input (use cin) and then write each line of the solution (not just spaces, but also the appropiate numbers). Hint: each row only has powers of 2

Comment: What is your question? This is not a mentor recruitment venue or a chat room, y'know.

Comment: @SaraVF: Actually, abstracting away the input from _stdin_ is a good thing for a MCVE. We encourage it.

Answer (score 2):

To correctly format your pyramid, **supposing you're using fixed width characters**, you need to know beforehand some information, e.g.:

- what is the largest number that you're going to print.
- how many numbers have which width.

Since the pyramid is increasing downwards, this information is available when you print the *last* line.

So what you need to do is to calculate (but not output, of course) the last line first. Say that you want five rows, then the middle number will be 2^(5-1), i.e. 16. So you will have to output 1 2 4 8 16. The column positions will be 0 (beginning), 2 (0 plus length of "1" plus 1 space), 4 (2 plus 1 plus 1 space), 6 (4 plus 1 plus 1), 8, 11 (8 plus length of "16" which is 2, plus 1 space), 13, 15, 17.

At this point you start output of the first line, beginning at column 5, i.e. at position 8.

The second line will start at column 4, i.e. at position 6.

And so on.

Another possibility is to imagine you're filling a table (as if you were generating a HTML table):
- fill it top to bottom
- "explore" every cell size the same way as above, in any order
- generate column positions accordingly
- print the table top to bottom

This requires only one round of calculations, but needs memory storage for the table itself.

**A shortcut** is to verify what is the **largest** number you're gonna print, and format *all* columns with that width. In this case 16 is 2 characters, so you add one space padding and output all columns padded to 3 character width. **This may waste unnecessary space**.

The latter case can be implemented using `cout.width`:

```
int main() {

    int line;

    // Read input from standard input
    cin >> line;

    // We output the pyramid by allocating a fixed width to each number.
    // This requires to know beforehand which will be the largest number.
    // We can observe that at every line, the largest number is 2 to the
    // power of that line number: on line 0, the largest number is 2^0
    // which is 1, on line 1 it is 2 which is 2^1... on line 4 it is 16
    // which is 2^4. So if we have five lines (from 0 to 4), the largest
    // number will be 2 to the 4th.

    // Now the length of a number in base 10 is given by the logarithm
    // base 10 of that number, truncated, plus 1. For example log10 of
    // 1000 is exactly 3, and 3+1 is 4 digits. Log10 of 999 is
    // 2.9995654... which truncates to 2, 2+1 is 3 and 999 is 3 digits.

    // Here our number is 2 to the power of (line-1).
    // By the properties of the logarithm
    // this is the same as (line-1)*log10(2), and log10(2) is around 0.3.

    // So we multiply (line-1) by log10(2), truncate to integer and add 1
    // (or vice versa: we add 1 and then assign to width, which is an
    // integer, thereby truncating the value to integer.

    // But we need to add another 1 for the padding space (we want 1 2 4
    // 2 1, not 12421...). So before assigning, we add 2, not 1.

    int width = 2+(line-1)*0.30102999566398119521373889472449;

    //////////////////////
    // TODO: we're gonna output 2*line+1 strings, each 'width' wide.
    // So if (2*line+1)*width > 80 we'd better say it and stop, or the
    // output will be sorely messed up, since a terminal is only 80 chars
    // wide at the most. Which means that N=9 is the maximum number we
    // can print out and still be "nice".
    // Having not been asked to do this, we proceed instead.
    //////////////////////

    // For every line that we need to output...
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
        // Pad line-i empty spaces
        for (int j = 0; j < (line-i); j++) {
            // Set the width of the next cout to "width" bytes
            cout.width(width);
            cout<<" ";
        }
        int n = 1;
        // output the forward sequence: 1, 2, 4... doubling each time
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            cout.width(width);
            cout <<n;
            n *= 2;
        }
        // output the top number, which is the next doubling
        cout.width(width);
        cout <<n;

        // output the sequence in reverse. Halve, output, repeat.
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            n /= 2;
            cout.width(width);
            cout<<n;
        }
        // Now n is 1 again (not that we care...), and we output newline
        cout <<"\n";
    }

    // Return 0 to signify "no error".
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with the code. But I can't compile it in my devc++. And cout.width(width) is new to me. Can you please explain this more elaborately. Thank you.

Comment: I'm too dumb. I forgot the #include. It worked perfectly. But can you elaborate cout.width(width) . What does it do specifically. Because our prof required us to provide a tracing of the program. And a flowchart at the same time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Look, the point of this exercise is to understand *why* you do something, and *how* it is done. If I were to supply that, first I would cheat you out of a valuable part of the exercise, and secondly you would be even worse set for the rest of the course - when you'll have to *build* over this part. I'll add some comments to the code, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Code. This will give the desire output .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int line = 4;
    for (int i =0; i < line; i++){
        for(int j = line - i; j >0 ; j --){
            cout<<"  ";
        }
        int temp = 1;
        for(int k = 0; k < i + 1; k ++){
            cout << " "<<temp;
            temp = temp *2;
        }
        temp /=2;
        for(int k =0; k < i; k ++){
            temp /=2;
            cout << " "<<temp;
        }
        cout <<"\n";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
        1
      1 2 1
    1 2 4 2 1
  1 2 4 8 4 2 1
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `line = 5`?  The OP's problem occurs when some number exceeds a single digit.

Comment: True. I think I'll just have to correct those. And that it should be base on the largest number in the middle not on the number of lines. Anyway, thank you for this.